# ADF: how to prevent the table to display automatically?

Tags: oracle-adf

I need to test the total time of reloading a table in the page. Now the problem is that, when I enter the page, the table and all data in it are displayed automatically. What I want is a button on the page and the table is shown after clicking on the button so that I can test the loading time precisely.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Easy way: add a panelTabbed and two showDetailItem tabs. Put the table in tab 2. Only when you click on tab 2 the first time does the fetch happen. Better way: set table iterator RefreshCondition to backing bean boolean variable. When user clicks button, in actionListener, set variable true. Put partial trigger of table to button id.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading the table , you should call executeEmptyRowset() . This would clear out the table content. More [here](http://www.jobinesh.com/2010/05/displaying-empty-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a condition set on the executable that populate the table and have its value controlled by you.
something like this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/delay_method_execution_when_us